# Should I still use getInstance() for SharedPreference with Hilt SingltonComponent?

Tags: android, kotlin, singleton, androidx, dagger-hilt

At the moment, I am using this code:

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DataStoreModule {
    @Provides
    fun providePreferencesDataStoreRepository(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) =
        PreferenceRepository.getInstance(appContext)
}
```

But as far as I know, when SingletonComponent is used, I don't need to use PreferenceRepository with getInstance(). So,

Is this code make it any differences?

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
class DataStoreModule {
    @Provides
    fun providePreferencesDataStoreRepository(@ApplicationContext appContext: Context) =
        PreferenceRepository(appContext)
}
```

I tried to decompile and check, but I don't know the place where I can see it.

I guess, PreferenceRepository should use getInstance() because the usage of this class itself should be clear. Is there any differences?

Answer (score 1):

The getInstance function shouldn't exist.    The point of injection is to get rid of static functions like that.  First off, they're very difficult to mock.  Secondly, they make your code less testable.  And if you're injecting an instance, there's no point in having it.  Nobody will ever call it outside of the injection framework.  Instead you should just make the class have a constructor, and delete any getInstance type methods.

Comment: What if I use it in Application or in other class such as Helper classes?

Comment: You should still be injecting it (or for a static helper function, passing it in as a parameter).  You don't do injection and singleton getInstance calls-  you use injection to get rid of those.  In fact using both is worse-  if you have a complex injection scheme its possible to get things out of sync with what a getInstance call returns.  There's no reason to have them if you have injection.